# Обработка запроса с сервера h2 spring boot

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-boot, get, h2

Есть база данных h2. В ней хранятся какие-то данные. Я могу получить строчку по такому запросу:

```
@GetMapping("/cproducts/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Optional<Product> tutorialData = productRepository.findById(id);

        if (productData.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(productData.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Как получить столбец (определенное значение колонки) из полученного запроса выше?
(т е из запроса выше мы получаем что-то по типу такого: {"id":1, "title":"first"}, а как получить из этого запроса только title?)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если достаточно вернуть простое строковое значение заданного поля, это можно сделать так (в отдельном методе контроллера):

```java
@GetMapping("/cproducts/{id}/title")
public ResponseEntity<?> getProductTitleById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return productRepository.findById(id)
        .map(p -> ResponseEntity.ok(product.getTitle()))
        .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Если нужно вернуть ответ в виде JSON-обёртки: `{"title": "my product title"}`, следует использовать DTO-класс (data transfer object) и преобразовать найденный товар в экземпляр DTO:

```java
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TitleDTO {
    private final String title;
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/cproducts/{id}/title")
public ResponseEntity<?> getProductTitleById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return productRepository.findById(id)
        .map(p -> ResponseEntity.ok(new TitleDTO(p.getTitle()))
        .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

---

В Spring 6 был добавлен метод [`ResponseEntity::ofNullable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ofNullable(T)), тогда код упростится:

```java
@GetMapping("/cproducts/{id}/title")
public ResponseEntity<String> getProductTitleById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ofNullable(productRepository.findById(id)
        .map(Product::getTitle)
        .orElse(null)
    );
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/cproducts/{id}/title")
public ResponseEntity<TitleDTO> getProductTitleById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ofNullable(productRepository.findById(id)
        .map(p -> new TitleDTO(p.getTitle()))
        .orElse(null)
    );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как выяснилось, можно немного проще:
```
@GetMapping("/cmaps/{id}/title")
 public ResponseEntity<String> getTutorialTitleById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
  ResponseEntity<String> res = ResponseEntity.ok().body(tutorialRepository.findById(id).get().getTitle());
  return res; }
```

Comment: В вашем коде в комментарии будет [выброшено `NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--), если элемент не будет найден в базе по `id`; безопаснее и логичнее использовать `Optional::orElse` / `Optional::orElseGet`